# Accessing a network share via a SQL Server 2012 Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

If you have a SQL Server Cluster called CLS, with machines CLS1 and CLS2, accessing:

```
\\CLS\network\path
```

is equivalent to accessing either

```
\\CLS1\network\path
```

or

```
\\CLS2\network\path
```

depending on whether CLS1 or CLS2 is the currently active instance.

The same behavior isn't occurring on a SQL Server 2012 Availability Group I've set up to try out AGs. I have three machines called PRI, SEC1 and SEC2 in an availability group called AG. I can access the databases via AG, and can remote desktop AG, but cannot access network shared via AG.

1. Are you supposed to be able to, by default, access networks shares via the AG?
2. If not, can this behavior be enabled?

Edit: I am primarily interested in the administrative shares (c$, d$ etc.)

Answer (score 1):

`CLS` is not an alias for either `CLS1` or `CLS2`. `CLS` is a cluster, not a real machine. You cannot access `\\CLS\c$` simply because no such thing exists. There is only `\\CLS1\C$` and `\\CLS2\C$` and you can access either of them. You should figure out which one is the one you're interested and access that.

Answer (score 0):

You need a shared disk inside the resource group to be able to add a shared folder in WFC.. So

```
\\CLS\path
```

Will only work if "path" is a shared folder on one of the SAN drives of the SQL Server Instance (if you share a folder on CLS1's C: drive it will not show up in \CLS even if CLS is on CLS1), this is because the "fileserver" resource in the resource group will fail if the resource group fails over and does not find the same C: drive as that on CLS1 on CLS2

Since AlwaysOn uses Standalone SQL Servers (only one resource group for the listener, with just an IP), it will not allow you to create a shared folder.. If you need a shared folder, you will need to do the following

1. Add a shared (clustered) drive to the Listener Resource Group
2. Right Click the resource group and choose "create a shared folder"
3. This share will then access from \AG\SharedFolder, where SharedFolder is a folder on the clustered drive from step 1

Comment: I seem to be able to access \\CLS\c$, and it passes through to \\CLS1\c$ or \\CLS2\c$ appropriately. I tested it was actually working by creating a blank text file on \\CLS\c$, it then appeared on \\CLS1\c$ but not on \\CLS2\c$.

Comment: It does not apply to dollar shares, try it with a shared folder..

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have been more specific. It's the administrative/dollar shares that I am primarily interested in. I have updated the question.

Comment: so i tried accessing \\CLS\c$ (note, by c drive I mean a drive that is not shared, and windows is installed on it), it did not work, with the same error "network path not found"